# How to read an NFC scan on android using MVVMCross

Tags: android, nfc, mvvmcross

I'm writing a plugin for mvvmcross to read and write nfc tags. As far as I can tell the best way to intercept Intents on droid is to cast the top activity to a `IMvxEventSourceActivity` as I have done here https://github.com/rossdargan/MvxPlugins/blob/master/NFC/DevelopingTrends.MvxPlugins.NFC.Droid/DroidBase.cs#L81

Are there any cases I might have missed with this approach, or is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Thanks

Ross